# Read binary string from file and save as hex

Tags: python, node.js, binary, hex

I have the file with lines like this: `\x8b\xe2=V\xa2\x050\x10\x1f\x11lvCh\x80\xf8z\xf8%\tHKE\xf2\xc8\x92\x12\x83\xe8R\xd3\xc8`
I need convert this string to hex code: `0x8be23d56a20530101f116c76436880f87af82509484b45f2c8921283e852d3c8`

I tried do this in python and nodejs. But if I do this in console mode - all work fine, if I reading from file, I have wrong result, because from file reads as quoted string.

Comment: "I tried do this… I have wrong result" is not something anyone can debug. Show us a [mcve] and we can show you what you did wrong.

Comment: Also, the answer isn't going to be the same for Python and for JavaScript, so don't ask a single question for both.

Comment: You tried `fs.readFileSync('filename').toString('hex')`?

Answer (score 3):

The string you are using in console application where "\" character does not count when you convert it to Buffer. Please use double back slash. There is no problem when you are reading data from file.

For NodeJs, Convert string into buffer and convert that buffer to hex value.

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('notes.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  const buf = Buffer.from(data, 'ascii');
  //converting string into buffer
  var hexvalue = buf.toString('hex');
  //with buffer, convert it into hex
  console.log(hexvalue);
});
```

For python, You can try this.

```
file = open("notes.txt","r")
str = file.readline()
str = str.encode('utf-8')
print (str.hex())
```

Comment: I get the hexvalue but when I convert from hexvalue to file using the below the line, it gets blank pdf.
const b1 = await Buffer.from(hexvalue, "hex");
fs.writeFileSync('copy-lic.pdf', hexvalue );

Answer (score 1):

For python:

```
import binascii
f = open('path/to/file', 'rb').read()
hex_encoded = binascii.hexlify(f).decode('utf-8')
print(hex_encoded) #Prints hex stream as string
```

Hope it helps